# One SSL Certificate Two Services

Tags: ssl, certificate, iis, ssl-certificate

I'm having trouble finding a clear answer to this question:

In IIS (7.5 or 8) I plan on hosting a site that will have a bunch of secure HTML eforms (default port 443).  They will be performing ajax operations against a service hosted on the same server, and same domain, but running on a different port (in the 50000 range).

Can I use the same SSL certificate for both of these 'sites' (web site & separate wcf service) within IIS since they will have the same hostname (with only a difference on the port being used)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the hostname is the same, there is no technical reason why you can't use the same certificate. However, there may be legal reasons -- some certificate issuers only license them for use on a single server. If it's two services on the same server it may be OK anyway, but you should carefully read the terms and conditions of your certificate issuer.

Comment: They would be on the same server.  I just want to host my service (WCF RESTful API) on a non-standard port and keep it separated from the website itself.  I couldn't quite tell if this was technically possible, so thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The certificate signs the public key of the server for a fully qualified domain name. The port is not part of it. You could even apply for a wildcard certificate for all hosts under a domain, i.e. *.domain.com.